# How to check two Time durations overlaps in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I have following signatures and predicate for checking two Time duration overlaps

```
sig Time{}
sig Duration{
   startTime : one Time,
   endTime : one Time
}
pred isTimeOverlap[a, b : Duration] {
//
}
```

I want to implement following logic in Alloy(as predicate isTimeOverlap). Is there any specific way to handle Time in Alloy

```
function Boolean isTimeOverlapp(Time $time1start, Time $time1end, Time $time2start, Time $time2end) {
   if(($time1start <= $time2end) && ($time2start <= $time1end)) {
        return TRUE;
   } else {
        return FALSE;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think alloy prefers a relational situation in this case. Note that Time is an (ordered) set. So between 2 Time atoms there are a number of other Time atoms. I.e. a range is a *set* of Time. Overlap is then a simple overlap in their set values. I.e. if they have any Time in common. Since each ordered atom has a `nexts` function you can easily calculate the members of a range.

```
open util/ordering[Time]

sig Time {}


let range[s,e] = (s + s.nexts) - e.nexts // inclusive bounds i.e. [s,e]
let overlap[s1,e1,s2,e2] = some (range[s1,e1] & range[s2,e2])

check {


    // [t0,t0] ∩ [t0,tn]
    overlap[ first, first, first, last ] 

    // [t0,t1] ∩ [t1,tn]
    overlap[ first, first.next, first.next, last ]

    // [t0,t1] ∩ [t0,tn]
    overlap[ first, first.next, first, last ]

    // [t0,t1] ∩ [t0,t1]
    overlap[ first, first.next, first, first.next ] 

    // not ( [t1,t0] ∩ [t0,t1] )
    not overlap[ first.next, first, first, last ]

    // not ( [t0,t1] ∩ [t2,tn] )
    not overlap[ first, first.next, first.next.next, last ] 

    // reflexive
    all t1, t2, t3,  t4 : Time | overlap[t1,t2,t3,t4] <=> overlap[t3,t4,t1,t2]
} for 10
```